# accessing Nested arrays in json from jsreport

Tags: arrays, json, jsrender, jsreport

I'm trying to parse nested arrays in jsreport using the jsrender engine and a {{for}} statement but It's going through the araay twice for some reason.  Here's my json data:

```
    "recordsOnFile": "4",
"invalidRecordsOnFile": "3",
"invalidRecordError": [
    {"row": "2"},{"error": [
        {"record": "In the field DateOfBirth."},{"record": "converting 0sass to type: m/d/yyyy."}
    ] 
    },
    {"row": "3"},{"error": [
        {"record": "in the field IsRehired"},{"record": "converting 11 to type: boolean."}
    ]
    },
    {"row": "4"},{"error": [
        {"record": "Invalid Ethnicity Code"}
    ]
    }
    ],
    "numberNewRecords": "0",
"newRecords": [
    {"nrecord": "0"}
    ],
"numberUpdatedRecords": "1",
"updatedRecords": [
    {"updatedRowNumber": "5"},{"updateRowInfo": "Casper1003 Harper5003"}
]
```

}

And here's my jsreport where I am parsing the nested arrays:

```
<div class="textLeft" id="showInvalidRecord">
{{for invalidRecordError}}
<div class="textLeftIndent">Row Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{:row}}</div>
<div class="textLeftIndent">Error(s):&nbsp;&nbsp;{{for error}}{{:record}}&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{/for}}</div>
{{/for}}
```

Why is it going through twice?  I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out I didn't need to nest arrays so this is no longer an issue.